# AZ Directory category

Tags: categories, directory, list

Hi i would like to create an A to Z index of category of 3 rows. How would i go about in doing this?
Example:

ABCDEFG...

A
title of category started with the letter A

B
title of category started with the letter B

C
title of category started with the letter C

D
title of category started with the letter D

E
title of category started with the letter E

F
title of category started with the letter F

G
title of category started with the letter G

etc...

Comment: What has been your research so far? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. More info about how to ask a good question can be found on the [ask] page.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on [Creating an Alphabetical Glossary of Posts](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/424/alphabetical-posts-glossary/) but here are the most relevant parts.

First create a hidden taxonomy for the letters of the alphabet

```
// Add new taxonomy, NOT hierarchical (like tags)
function kia_create_glossary_taxonomy(){
    if(!taxonomy_exists('glossary')){
        register_taxonomy('glossary',array('post'),array(
        'show_ui' => false
      ));
     }
}
add_action('init','kia_create_glossary_taxonomy');
```

Then when any post is saved, save the first letter as the term in the glossary taxonomy

```
/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function kia_save_first_letter( $post_id ) {
// verify if this is an auto save routine.
// If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
return;

//check location (only run for posts)
$limitPostTypes = array('post');
if (!in_array($_POST['post_type'], $limitPostTypes)) return;

// Check permissions
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
return;

// OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
$taxonomy = 'glossary';

//set term as first letter of post title, lower case
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, strtolower(substr($_POST['post_title'], 0, 1)), $taxonomy );

//delete the transient that is storing the alphabet letters
delete_transient( 'kia_archive_alphabet');
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'kia_save_first_letter' );
```

And voila, now know you have terms A, B, C, etc that should each contain all the posts whose titles began with that letter.